# Spivak Calculus on Manifolds Problem 5-31

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

Not sure how to go about b). a) is simple, but is there any way to prove b) without actually computing the cross product, etc in the general case?

Comment: Given that Spivak doesn’t introduce the Hodge star (well, not explicitly anyway), your best bet is to just brute-force it (but tbh, it’s not even that bad).

Comment: Please take the time to type out the question rather than posting a picture. Pictures cannot be searched for...

Comment: Think about the cross-product computed as a (formal) determinant. Isn't $dx(v\times w) = (dy\wedge dz)(v,w)$?

Comment: @TedShifrin How did you get that equation? What does the cross product have to do with the wedge?

Comment: Both are alternating bilinear functions of two vectors, one vector-valued, the other scalar-valued. But a vector has three scalar components. So this is hardly shocking. Why don’t you just do the calculations and verify what I said?

Comment: Hint: Ted Shifrin's formula follows from $dx(u)=u^x$ (the  $x$-component of $u$) and its analogues for $dy,dz\,.$ That follows in turn from $dx_i(\partial_j)=\delta_{ij}$ (forms are the duals of vectors).